# Create link in JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am having difficulty figuring where to insert and how to make a click function when users click/select an autocomplete item. I then want to do a DB query with the clicked item.

My current autocomplete script:

```
$("#search_customer").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1,       
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.content.length) {
                var create_customer = alert('bla bla...');
                    if (create_customer)
                    {
                    console.log('yes');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    console.log('no');
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `select` callback of jquery ui autocomplete
e.g

```
$("#search_customer").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 1,  
        select: function(event,ui) {
             var label = ui.item.label; // label of selected item
             var value = ui.item.value; // value of selected item
             // then make an ajax call here to get the data from db.
        },  
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.content.length) {
                var create_customer = alert('bla bla...');
                    if (create_customer)
                    {
                    console.log('yes');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    console.log('no');
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.